# XBMC w/WD MyCloud (NAS)

Tags: media-server

Has anyone ever done this? or is it possible.

Right now I have my WD MyCloud (It's a network attached storage) hooked up to my ASUS Wireless router, im able to stream video via DLNA to an XBOX ONE. It works, but the XBOX ONE Media player is very basic.

I have a Raspberry Pi and want to toss a Wireless adapter on it (any suggestions btw on the "fastest" one, cost isn't a factor). My idea is to have the Raspberry Pi use the WD MyCloud as a "Media Source" and be able to stream media to the Raspberry Pi. Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: Welcome to rpi.stackexchange! I have read you question several times, and I simply can't get my head around it. It's full of product references and acronyms, but I don't understand what you want to do, what you tried, what the outcome of your trial where, or how it differed from the result you expected. Please have another look at your question and see if you can make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is to have the Raspberry Pi use the WD MyCloud as a "Media Source" and be able to stream media to the Raspberry Pi.

Since you've said the drive has DNLA functionality, and there are various DNLA servers and clients available for GNU/Linux (including Raspbian), the simple solution is to set up a DNLA client on the pi.